# Pandas read_table returns â€™ characters

Tags: python, file, pandas, text, encoding

I'm seeing things like `â€™` after reading a text file with read_table(). The input file contents appear as ordinary ASCII characters in Windows Notepad.

```
dataRaw = pd.read_table('data.txt', header=None)
```

Do I need to include some character set parameter to prevent this?

Comment: You have an encoding problem. `â€™` is an incorrectly decoded apostrophe.

Comment: There is no such thing as a text file.  All files are just bytes.  You have to know what the bytes mean.

Comment: Does that mean there's no such thing as a binary file, either?

Comment: Okay, I know it's an encoding problem. Windows Notepad decodes it correctly, pandas.read_table (with default parameters) does not. The question is: now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It took two steps: (1) use the correct encoding; (2) convert things that are supposed to be apostrophes to apostrophes.

```
for line in open(dataPath, encoding='utf-8'):
   outstr = re.sub(r'[´]', '’', line)  # replace non-ASCII tick with apostrophe
   outstr = re.sub('[\']', '’', outstr)  # replace single quote with apostrophe
```

Thanks for the tip.